# how to compare between two Tuples?

Tags: python

Write a function commonElements(t1, t2) that takes in 2 tuples as arguments and returns a sorted tuple containing elements that are found in both tuples.

Examples

```
>>> commonElements((1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 1))
(1, 2)
>>> commonElements((1, 2, 3, 'p', 'n'), (2, 5 ,1, 'p'))
(1, 2, 'p')
>>> commonElements((1, 3, 'p', 'n'), ('a', 2 , 5, 1, 'p'))
(1, 'p')
```

i want to compare between two tuples

```
 def commonElements(t1,t2):
     if t1 in t2:
        return t1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tuple Comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405122/tuple-comparison)

Comment: yes but it give me errors

Comment: add what you have tried

Comment: def commonElements(t1,t2):
 if t1 in t2:
  return t1

Comment: i want to be professional in python but i don`t know what shall i do :) i am a beginner i want some helps and advices :)

Comment: Grab a book and stop posting your homework in stack overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to check if each element `in` t1 is `in` t2, your code just returns `t1` when you find the first common element or None if there are no common elements:

```
def commonElements(t1,t2):
    temp = []  # store  common elements
    st2  = set(t2)
    for ele in t1: # loop over each element in t1
        if ele in st2: # if it is in t2 add it to or temp list, set lookups are O(1)
            temp.append(ele)
    return tuple(sorted(temp)) # sort temp and convert to a tuple

In [4]: commonElements((1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 1))
Out[4]: (1, 2)

In [5]: commonElements((1, 2, 3, 'p', 'n'), (2, 5 ,1, 'p'))
Out[5]: (1, 2, 'p')

In [6]: commonElements((1, 3, 'p', 'n'), ('a', 2 , 5, 1, 'p'))
Out[6]: (1, 'p')
```

You can also use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) or a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
def  commonElements(t1,t2):
     # find the intersection/common elements
    return tuple(sorted(set(t1).intersection(t2)))

def  commonElements(t1,t2):
    return tuple(sorted(ele for ele in t1 if ele in t2))
```

Comment: @vaultah, where does it say python 3?

Comment: @vaultah, well presuming the task is to sort the output i imagine the teacher is not going to give a beginner that problem

Comment: i want some advices to be professional in python @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @RamyGeorge, sets are most efficient if dealing with large amounts of data.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i want to be professional coder what shall i do ?

Comment: @RamyGeorge, the python practice book is a really useful resource http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/getting-started.html

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you very much :) 

i want to ask another question can we make computer do 2+2=7 ?

Comment: @RamyGeorge, not without hardcoding it some way

Comment: what do you mean by hardcoding ? can you explain ?

Comment: @RamyGeorge, without changing your python  implementation source you would have to use run the code through some function

Answer (score 1):

You could use operator based intersection of sets .

```
def commonElements(one, two):
    return tuple(sorted(set(one) & set(two)))

commonElements((1,2,3), (2,3,4))
# (2, 3)
```