# Tuple comparison 'A' == ('A'), how to avoid that?

Tags: python, tuples, equality

I was puzzled by seeing that python returns True for a comparison like this:
'A' == ('A')

then I found [this](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin) explanation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405122/tuple-comparison) question.

Python compares every element in the tuple to the other term of comparison. 
My question is **how can I avoid that?**
What I'm looking for is a '==' logical operator that returns True for  'A' == 'A' or ('A') == ('A') but false for 'A' ==' ('A').

Comment: `('A')` is not a tuple, is it? `type(('A'))` returns `str`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I wasn't aware defining a single element tuple was a special case.

Comment: The comma defines a tuple, not the parentheses. The exception is the empty tuple `()`, which could (should?) have been written `(,)`, but `()` wasn't needed to represent any parenthesized expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your "explanation" has nothing to do with your actual problem.

`('A')` is *not* a tuple. It is simply a string. A single-element tuple is defined like this: `('A',)`. When you use an actual tuple, your comparison correctly  returns False:

```
>>> 'A' == ('A',)
False
```

Comment: nailed it. I guess I have to study more accurately the issue of commas after tuples.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is already there provided by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman). Just an addition:

```
>>> type("A")
<type 'str'>

>>> type(("A"))
<type 'str'>

>>> type(("A",))
<type 'tuple'>
```